# Play audio (mp3) on hovering over html button

Tags: javascript, html, audio, mp3

Several years ago I wrote some html pages to display Dante's Divina Commedia and to play audio files containing associated comment and actual reading.

This project seems to have undergone a severe case of bit-rot.

Audio is not working anymore and also formatting is not good.

Project is quite big (mostly due to audio files, but also the pages are not trivial).

Since I am NOT a web programmer (I'm mainly a C/C++/Java programmer) I would like some advice before I try to revamp this code.

Core part is the following javascript (trimmed for terseness, I can send the whole thing, if useful):

```
function writeTable() {
        document.write('<TABLE border="1" width="100%">',
                       '  <tr>',
                       '    <td rowspan="3" width="60%">');
        conditionalParagraph(true);
        document.write('      <form name=f1>',
                       '        <input disabled class="select" type="button" name="b1" value="Canto I" style="height:120; font-size:28pt">',
                       '      </form>');
        conditionalParagraph(false);
        document.write('    </td>',
                       '    <td>');
        conditionalParagraph(true);
        document.write('      <form name=f4>',
                       '        <input class="select" type="button" name="b4" value="Immagine" onclick="switchImmagine()">',
                       '      </form>');
        conditionalParagraph(false);
        document.write('    </td>',
                       '    <td rowspan="3" width="80" height="120">',
                       '       <img name="foto" src="../../img/sermonti_vittorio.jpg" onclick="setPlaying(0)">',
                       '    </td>',
                   '  </tr>',
                       '  <tr>',
                       '    <td>');
        conditionalParagraph(true);
        document.write('      <form name=f2>',
                       '        <input class="select" type="button" name="b2" value="Commento" onMouseOver="commentoOver()" onclick="setPlaying(1)" onMouseOut="commentoOut()">',
                       '      </form>');
        conditionalParagraph(false);
        document.write('    </td>',
                       '  </tr>',
                       '  <tr>',
                       '    <td>');
        conditionalParagraph(true);
        document.write('      <form name=f3>',
                       '        <input class="select" type="button" name="b3" value="Lettura" onMouseOver="letturaOver()" onclick="setPlaying(2)" onMouseOut="letturaOut()">',
                       '      </form>');
        conditionalParagraph(false);
        document.write('    </td>',
                       '  </tr>',
                       '</table>');
}


var playing = 0;

function playC(b) {
        if (b)
                if (navigator.family == "gecko")
                        document.audioCommento.Play(false);
                else
                        document.audioCommento.Play();
        else
                document.audioCommento.Stop();
}

function playL(b) {
        if (b)
                if (navigator.family == "gecko")
                    document.audioLettura.Play(false);
                else
                document.audioLettura.Play();
        else
                document.audioLettura.Stop();
}

function commentoOver() {
            if (playing == 0) {
                document.foto.src="../../img/sermonti_vittorio.jpg";
                top.frames["pagina"].playC(true);
        }
}

function letturaOver() {
        if (playing == 0) {
                document.foto.src="../../img/dante_alighieri.jpg";
                        top.frames["pagina"].playL(true);
        }
}

function commentoOut() {
        if (playing == 0) {
                top.frames["pagina"].playC(false);
        }
}

function letturaOut() {
        if (playing == 0) {
                top.frames["pagina"].playL(false);
        }
}
```

Main problem is with Firefox and Chrome I do not hear anything neither hovering over the generated buttons nor clicking on them, while with IE *both* audio files (commento and lettura) start immediately and it is not possible to stop them.

Minor problem is the generated table with buttons is not "packed" (i.e.: there is spurious vertical space between buttons which was *not* there years ago).

Can someone suggest an easy fix?
In absence of such: what is the current best practice to achieve this effect (and prevent further bit-rot).

I think I've been using some non-standard property that changed in the years; can someone confirm this, please?

TiA
Mauro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all the browsers support same audio file formats. Have a look [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_audio.asp).
Basicaly, :

```
Browser MP3 Wav Ogg
IE      YES NO  NO
Chrome  YES YES YES
Firefox NO  YES YES
Update: Firefox 21 running on Windows 7, Windows 8, Windows Vista, and Android now supports MP3 
Safari  YES YES NO
Opera   NO  YES YES
```

However, you can have a look at [this](http://css-tricks.com/play-sound-on-hover/), which explains very easily how you can play audios on hover using CSS.

Comment: I have a set of big .mp3 (converting to .ogg is not an option at the moment and having two versions is absolutely out of question). It is unclear to me if technique explained in the pointed article does apply to my case; can You confirm, please? It seems suitable for short "beeps", not to play a long speech possibly suspending and resuming.

Comment: Well, there is a site called http://www.reverbnation.com/ that plays music by streaming it. 1 possible option for you could be that you can convert them to flash format so that the content gets played irrespective of the browser. Another thing to note is that playing a relly long audio just "onhover" may not be a good user experience from the UI/UX point of view. But in anycase, even if you want to do it, may flash is an option for you. that way the streaming will also save the end users to fully wait for the audio to load and then play. Like Youtube and etc.

Comment: Recent versions of my installed browsers all seem to support .mp3. Simply switching to HTML5 <audio> tagging solved my problem. I didn't even need to use the <source> inner tag; using <audio> "src" attribute was enough.